# Labels are loading slowly in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, performance

I am trying to speed up the process of loading labels in ArcMap. There are few layers containing labels that have a conditional form (not only in content but also text formatting). According to [Esri guide](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/optimizing-map-text-and-labels-for-performance.htm):

> Label expressions slow drawing performance. In particular, avoid using
>   label expression scripts to conditionally parse or format label
>   strings or to concatenate the information in multiple fields into one
>   label string when drawn. Instead, calculate a new field with exactly
>   the information that is needed. The field can include formatting tags.

So instead of using label expressions I stored strings in Attribute Table. 
I expected a lot faster loading, but labels are loading even a bit slower than before! What am I doing wrong?
Here is an example of label string:

```
<LIN leading = '-5'><FNT size='8' name='Arial narrow CE'><ITA>  So120-1.0</ITA></FNT> <FNT size='8' name='Arial narrow CE'><ITA>a </ITA></FNT><SUP><FNT size='8' name='Arial'>_____________</FNT></SUP></LIN> <LIN leading = '-5'><FNT size='8' name='Arial narrow CE'><ITA>1.63</ITA></FNT></LIN>
```

Comment: You might try adding in a layer multiple times with different definition queries, one for each different style, with the actual text you want in the label sitting in a single field.  You might also  look at your label settings, including maplex fast v best,  quality, placement, postiion, etc. and label weights.  Almost any of these can affect your speed.  Having a basemap, say one from ESRI, also adds to redraw speeds which becomes noticeable with large numbers of labels.  Sometimes you just have to convert the labels to annotation to get the needed performance.

Comment: My project has a very strict policy about labels placement so I can't really mess with that. I don't use any basemap. Annotations give good performance, but it's not very flexible. I will try with different definition queries, maybe that will help.

Comment: @johns I just realised that you were probably thinking about switching off part of labels after splitting them in multiple layers. Unfortunately, I need to see them all at once...